# ultrafilter is principal if and only if it contains a finite set

Tags: general-topology, filters

Prove that an ultrafilter is principal if and only if it contains a finite set.

> First we will show that an ultrafilter is principal if it contains a finite set.
>
> Define a principal ultrafilter
> $$\mathscr{U}_{x}=\{U \subseteq I | x \in U\}$$
> Note that $\{x\}$ is always an element of  $\mathscr{U}_{x}$, thus every principal ultrafilter contains a finite set.
>
> Now we want to show that if an ultrafilter contains a finite set then it is principal.
>
> Let $\mathscr{U}$ be an ultrafilter on $I$ and let U be a finite subset of $\mathscr{U}$.

I am stuck here. I know I need to show that there is an $x \in U$ such that $\{x\} \in \mathscr{U}$ which will imply that $\mathscr{U} = \mathscr{U}_x$. I am not sure how to find\define such an x. Can I just let an $x \in U$ and go from there??

Comment: I’ve been a bit busy today, but I finally found time to answer your comment at my answer to your earlier question.

Answer (score 2):

Prove the lemma: if $F \cup G \in \mathcal{U}$ then $F \in \mathcal{U}$ or $G \in \mathcal{U}$ when $\mathcal{U}$ is an ultrafilter. By induction, this extends to finite unions as well. Apply that to a finite set, split into singletons.

---

The lemma follows from the following fact on ultrafilters $\mathcal{U}$ on $X$:

> $(\ast)$ For every $A\subseteq X$ either $A \in \mathcal{U}$ or $X\setminus A \in \mathcal{U}$.

Suppose we know this fact and $F \cup G \in \mathcal{U}$ and $F \notin \mathcal{U}$ *and* $G \notin \mathcal{U}$ then by this fact $F^c \in \mathcal{U}$ and $G^c \in \mathcal{U}$ and so $F^c \cap G^c \in \mathcal{U}$. But $(F \cup G) \cap (F^c \cap G^c)=\emptyset$, so we'd have a contradiction. So $F \in \mathcal{U}$ or $G \in \mathcal{U}$ must hold.

The proof of the fact $(\ast)$ follows from the maximality of $\mathcal{U}$: if $A \not \mathcal{U}$ this means there exists some $U \in \mathcal{U}$ such that $A \cap U = \emptyset$. Why? If this were **not** the case, $A$ would have non-empty intersection with *all* $U \in \mathcal{U}$ but then $\mathcal{U}':= \{B \subseteq X\mid \exists U \in \mathcal{U}: U \cap A \subseteq B\}$ would be a strictly larger (as $A \in \mathcal{U}'\setminus \mathcal{U}$) filter on $X$, which cannnot be!; (check that this is indeed a filter under these circumstances)
Having such a $U$ we then have that $A \cap U = \emptyset$ so $U \subseteq A^c$ and as $U \in \mathcal{U}$ and filters are closed under supersets, $A^c \in \mathcal{U}$ and we have shown that whenever $A \notin \mathcal{U}$ then $A^c \in \mathcal{U}$, which is what we wanted.